# How to pass the payload of C# in VScode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, openai-api, payload, bad-request

I was trying to create a code translator in C# using OpenAI (Api Reference : https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create). Got result on Postman and the code got translated.
To make it more interesting, I have tried to work the same on VSCode and the code I have used is below:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OpenAIProgram
{
    public class CodeTranslator
    {
        public static async Task<string> TranslateCodeAsync(string apiKey, string apiUrl, string jsonBody)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiUrl) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonBody))
                    throw new Exception("Missing parameter for execution");

                using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiUrl);
                request.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                request.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Response code was " + response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = e.Message;
                result += "\n" + e.GetType() + ": " + e.Message;
                if (e.StackTrace != null)
                {
                    foreach (var trace in e.StackTrace.Split("\n"))
                    {
                        result += "\n\t" + trace.Trim();
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static async Task Main()
        {
            string apiKey = "---";
            string apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
            string jsonBody = @"
{
    ""model"": ""gpt-3.5-turbo"",
    ""messages"": [
        {
            ""role"": ""system"",
            ""content"": ""Ready to Translate .""
        },
        {
            ""role"": ""user"",
            ""content"": ""class FibonacciExample1{public static void main(String[] args){int n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,count=10;System.out.print(n1+"" + n2); for (i = 2; i < count; ++i) { n3 = n1 + n2; System.out.print(\"" + n3 + ""\""); n1 = n2; n2 = n3; }} }""
        },
        {
            ""role"": ""system"",
            ""content"": ""Translate the code from[Java] to[Python].""
        }
    ],
    ""temperature"": 1.0,
    ""max_tokens"": 150
}";

            // Translate the code
            string translatedCode = await TranslateCodeAsync(apiKey, apiUrl, jsonBody);

            Console.WriteLine(translatedCode);
        }
    }
}
```

The Error iam getting is :

[image: Response code: BadRequest]

So, I got the idea that, this might be the issue with the Payload which I have given. Welcoming all to help me solve this issue.

Tried changing the Format of the `jsonBody` and the result were all same.

Comment: Can you just check if your json body is valid json? The content with the actual code you want to translate does not look like that. Especially the first call to print and the usage of quotes there.

Comment: The doubt Iam having was based on the json body only. I have tried giving simple codes like converting from python to c# (Hello World Program) and it's working.

Once Iam working with this type of code/content, 
 ""content"": ""class FibonacciExample1{public static void main(String[] args){int n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,count=10;System.out.print(n1+"" + n2); for (i = 2; i < count; ++i) { n3 = n1 + n2; System.out.print(\"" + n3 + ""\""); n1 = n2; n2 = n3; }} }""

        It's giving error. So, need to get an idea about the syntax for the same.

Comment: `System.out.print(n1+"" + n2)` the escaped double quote looks wrong here.  If you really wanted an empty string here it should be 4 double quotes.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the (""-- "") method. The Main doubt i have is with the verbatim literal strings. Should i consider these before curly brackets{} and () and "". Need to get a proper Idea on the same.

Comment: I can't follow you completely but if you have trouble getting the escaping right and you are on NET7 you might want to go for raw strings instead. Just take the working json from Postman and surround it with as many quotes as needed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/raw-string-literal